# Apex encoding signature

Tags: vb.net, cryptography, digital-signature, apex

I am trying to re-write the following VB function in Apex:

```
Private Shared Function sign(ByVal data As String, ByVal secretKey As String) As String

    Dim encoder As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
    Dim key() As Byte = encoder.GetBytes(secretKey)
    Dim dataAsBytes() As Byte = encoder.GetBytes(data)

    Dim myHMACSHA256 As New System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(key)
    Dim HashCode As Byte() = myHMACSHA256.ComputeHash(dataAsBytes)

    Return Convert.ToBase64String(HashCode)

End Function
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can create signature:

```
 String policy = '{ "expiration":"' + expires + '",' +   
    '"conditions":[';
    List<String> clauses = new List<String>{};
 for(List<String> clause : conditions){
    clauses.add(genCondition(clause));
 }
 String conditionsString = String.join(clauses,',');
 policy += conditionsString;
 policy += ']}';        
 policy = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(policy));  


signature = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA1', Blob.valueOf(base64EncodedPolicy), Blob.valueOf(Secret)));
```